# Wrap over the showed text when using vimwiki

Tags: vim, word-wrap

I'm using vimwiki, that allows you to write links like `[[wiki link ...|name link]]`.
If you're in edit mode and in a line with a link, then you see the real file content, otherwise you just see "name link". (In a similar fashion to the vim help |links|).

But vim, to calculate the wrap, uses the real content and not the displayed content.

I would like for vim to use the displayed characters to calculate the wrap.

Comment: There are many similar issues. I recently asked the question about one of them, you might want to check it out: http://goo.gl/AkmRW . I wrote to vim-dev and asked about working on it, Christian Brabandt said: "I think it is somewhere in the todo list together with the other conceal issues. I don't know, if this is actively being worked on."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

vimwiki uses the relatively new *conceal* feature to hide parts of the link, like the Vim help does with its markup. The illusion of hidden text isn't very deep, though, and Vim commands as well as the line wrapping still operate on the full text. The core Vim implementation would need to be extended to get what you want; someone needs to write a patch (and corresponding tests).

However, it's unclear how far this should be taken. After all, Vim is a text editor, not WYSIWYG. The *conceal* feature is a nice convenience and optical trick, not a core feature.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Vim will not be WYSIWYG editor if it have less conceal issues.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using conceal feature you can manage state of the actual content which is eventually written on the disk. As you can see this is a complicated approach and ridden with edge cases which risk data loss. A web equivalent of this would be rich text editors which are notoriously hard to get *right*.